# JToken.FromObject adds extra curly brackets C#

Tags: c#, object, json.net

Using Jtoken.FromObject results in double curly brackets which results in a JSON parse error, here is a simple example

```
object jtokenObject = new { Data = JToken.FromObject(new {Name="some name"}) };
Console.WriteLine(jtokenObject);
//{ Data = {{  "Name": "some name"}} }
JToken anotherToken = JToken.FromObject(jtokenObject);
Console.WriteLine(anotherToken);
//{{  "Data": {    "Name": "some name"  }}}
```

Does anyone know about a quick fix that does not require converting to string and removing or serializing / deserializing?

Comment: `JObject`'s implementation of `ToString()` does this.  If you want to write correct JSON, serialize it properly instead of counting on ToString():  `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)` will produce syntactically correct JSON.

Comment: Gotta ask; why are you setting an object's property to a JToken, then making that object a JToken? Seems like you'd be better off just doing `JToken.FromObject(new { Data = new { Name = "some name" } })` Probably won't help with the double brackets, but would reduce the amount of code you have.

Comment: Amy, I would like to not use serialization nor ToString, this seems like a bug in the JToken class but I'm wondering if there is a simple workaround. Heretic, i did it to highlight the issue. I added the result of the first line to make it more clear

Comment: @JrBriones You are using `ToString()` *right now*.  The simple "workaround" is to serialize it, as I said in my first comment.  If you want to produce syntactically-correct JSON, perform serialization.  I don't understand why that is undesired.

Comment: This is Newtonsoft.Json version dependent. I get the expected results in 12.0.3

Comment: Amy, The reason why that is undesired is because I'm passing that JToken as part of a "payload" and i want to manipulate as Jtoken at the receiving endpoint without having to deserialize/serialize. The ToString is only to display the result, the object inside the Jtoken still has the 2 curly brackets which is incorrect JSON